# How do I configure .vimrc so that line numbers display in netrw in Vim?

Tags: vim, netrw

I'm using netrw to read directory listings in Vim, and I would like to display line numbers in my netrw tabs (so I can use :24 to navigate through directory listings faster). I'm using "set number" in my vimrc to enable line numbers when editing files, but this does not display line numbers in netrw.

When in netrw, if I type the command ":set number", the line numbers display, but as soon as I change directories the line numbers go away.

Is there a configuration option I can put in .vimrc that will make line numbers show up in netrw windows?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

From `autoload/netrw.vim` in the runtime:

```
call s:NetrwInit("g:netrw_bufsettings" , "noma nomod nonu nobl nowrap ro")
```

`s:NetrwInit` overrides a variable only if it is not defined.

Therefore put `let g:netrw_bufsettings = 'noma nomod nu nobl nowrap ro'` into your `vimrc` and it should be ok.

Comment: You have a typo in your vimrc, missing the underscore in "g:netrw_bufsettings", but thanks - that's exactly what I needed.